Why is the competitive equilibrium price not well defined in this question?
Consider a market demand function p = 100 − q, where p is
market price and q is aggregate demand. There is a large number
of firms with identical cost functions
ci(qi) = 10 + 2qi, if qi > 0
         0, otherwise

Solving the cost function, I am getting that Marginal Cost is equal to 2. For a competitive equilibrium price, we set Price equal to Marginal Cost. So, price = 2. But the answer says that competitive equilibrium price is not well defined.
Could anyone please explain this to me? Why is it not well defined?

Competitive Equilibrium does not exist in this case. This is because at $p=2$, firm will choose to produce $0$ and that is not equal to the demand which is $98$.

Can you please explain why would the firm choose to produce 0 units at price = 2?

@Shreya because by producing $98$ (or any non zero quantity), it would have a profit of $-10$, which is worse than having a profit of $0$ which is achieved by producing $0$.

Solution: Your approach is right but it wont work in this situation as there are certain avoidable fixed costs associated with your cost function.
we are given the demand function as, $p^d(q)=100-q$ (i.e., $q^d(p)=100-p$)and the cost function as
$c_i(q_i)= (10+2q_i)\mathbb{I}_{(q_i \in (0,\infty))}$ which tells us that there are avoidable fixed costs of 10.
Now we can setup the firm's optimization problem,
$$\max_{\{q_i\}} \hspace{4mm} pq_i-(10+2q_i) \mathbb{I}_{(q_i \in (0,\infty))}$$
if we solve the above problem, we will get the supply as a function of price(p) for firm i,
$$q_i^s(p)= \cases{\{0\}, & \text{$p \le 2$}\\ \infty, & \text{otherwise} } $$
Notice that the markets wont clear for any price $p \le 2$ as the firms wont be willing to produce anything and for price $p >2$,the firms are ready to produce $+\infty$ amounts of quantity, Thus even in this case, the market wont clear.
Hence, There doesn't exist a competitive equilibrium.

The cost functions precise definition makes it clear that these are quasi-fixed costs, not fixed costs, which would occur even when $q=0$.

Yeah you are right. I should have used the term "avoidable fixed costs", so do you also mean the same thing by quasi-fixed costs?

Yes. There is one more occurence "which tells us that there are fixed costs of 10"

Yeah thanks for your inputs @Giskard
